# How to determine semantic differences in NLP

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

I would need to determine the difference in meaning between the following two sentences:

```
I am at home
I am not at home
I am at the office
```

the first two sentences differs in verb, which changes the meaning of the sentences (to negative); the second one, with the first one, differs because of the place.
I have thought of word2vec, but I am not completely sure if this is the best tool to analyse sentences like the above ones. Also cosine_similarity could be a solution, but I would have not information about the meaning. I think it is more about semantic meaning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, something like Google's Universal Sentence Encoder (USE) may work for your use-case. Many of the common NLP embedding techniques nowadays work on individual words and so creating sentence-level embeddings means averaging multiple word-level vectors together. USE was built to operate at the sentence level, so you may find it better.

The original paper can be found here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11175

An example blog post leveraging USE:
https://medium.com/@gaurav5430/universal-sentence-encoding-7d440fd3c7c7